# org.hibernate.validator.Length max value

Tags: java, hibernate, seam

I'm using the annotation @Length on a String:

```
@Length
private String variable;
```

I know that i can set a maximum value on this annotation, but does anyone knows if it is possible to set an unlimited max value?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For both `javax.validation.Length` and [`org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/Length.html#max%28%29) the default value is:

```
int max() default Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

i.e. 2147483647. So, not quite unlimited, but enough.

If this doesn't suit you, you can define your own constraint (per JSR 303 - javax.validation) and use a long param instead of int.

Answer (score 2):

> I know that i can set a maximum value on this annotation, but does anyone knows if it is possible to set an unlimited max value?

The `max` is an `int` and defaults to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. And since the Java String API does NOT support Strings longer than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` characters (such a String would require more than 4GB of storage), this is coherent. And allowing a bigger size at the constraint level is definitely **not**.

And by the way, an unlimited max value doesn't make much sense as "constraint". If you don't want to constraint something, don't define a constraint.

As a side note, I suggest to use the standard [`@Size`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17410_01/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Size.html) from bean validation instead of the [`@Length`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/Length.html#max%28%29) annotation from Hibernate Validator.